# Windows key + <Button> shortcuts not working after driver update

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, modern-ui, windows-key

I have reinstalled *Windows 8.1* on my laptop.

My problem is, that, after connecting to the Internet and letting windows install the drivers automatically, the **windows key** does not work normally.

Before, it would work on key release and with shortcuts normally.

But after installing the drivers, the windows key works on *press* instead of *release*.

Instead of executing with *shortcuts*, it just *brings up the metro display*.

Keeping it held down, it repeatedly switched between metro display and desktop.

It isn't a hardware issue, I tried reinstalling Windows and it works again on a fresh install, but it always switches on driver installation.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you download the drivers from the manufacture's website? Usually for laptops there are some drivers compatible with your system that the manufacturer puts on their website. Sometimes even updates cause "bugs" on the system.

Comment: I let Windows automatically update drivers, didn't download any manually. It worked just fine before, when I did this able half a year ago, but this time, it seems to have changed.

Comment: This might happen since there could be a newer version of the driver, provided by windows. Better go to your laptop's website and download the drivers from there. To not reinstall the windows again, try to uninstall all the updates and drivers from the control panel and device manager. If you want more help or a detailed answer, let me know so I can write a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the latest Windows update. I currently have Windows 8.1 and restarted for updates to install this morning. Now when I hold the Windows key, the Start menu flashes repeatedly.

I thought it might be a hardware problem, so I plugged the keyboard into someone else's laptop. The key worked fine when held, so it must be a software problem.